# Yesod devel fails, thought cabal build succeeds

Tags: haskell, cabal, yesod

I am relatively new to Haskell, coming from F# (a Microsoft language).

I have created a Yesod project from the scaffolder, played with it a bit, tweaked stuff, but then it stopped working, with this error message (after all modules were built successfully):

```
devel.hs: D:\yesod\projects\test101\dist\build\HStest101-0.0.0.o: unknown symbol `___stginit_test101zm0zi0zi0_HandlerziPage_'
devel.hs: devel.hs: unable to load package `test101-0.0.0'
Exit code: ExitFailure 1
```

By using cabal directly (`cabal build`, `cabal install`, `dist\build\test101\test101`) I was able to run the application, but this is really annoying.

What can I do?

Thanks!

Comment: What changes have you made? Have you tried rebuilding it from scratch using `cabal clean`?

Comment: Made some simple code changes: added db entities, changed routes, added a handler and changed the Root handler. Yes, I have cleaned.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you need to add your new modules (Handler.Page in particular) to the cabal file.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Solved everything!